# How do I create an Alarm on EC2 , which triggers if the instance is kept on for more than 6 hrs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried to set-up something which monitors NetworkPacketsOut. If the threshold crosses 50 for a period of 6hrs, the alarm is triggered. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RoO8.png)) 
But the logic seems to be faulty because this just keeps my alarm "always triggered" (In Alarm state). How do I fix this?

Comment: What screenshot?

Comment: Until the condition that triggered the Alarm does not change it keeps it in Alarm state. Please attach screenshot

Comment: Added the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this in Amazon CloudWatch because there is no metric for "run time".

Instead, you could create an AWS Lambda function that gets triggered on a regular basis and then checks whether the instances have been running too long.

Here is an example I wrote: [Simple EC2 Stopinator in Lambda](https://dev.to/aws/simple-ec2-stopinator-in-lambda-5goj). It uses Tags to configure how long an instance should be running before a notification is sent, or the instance can be automatically stopped/terminated.

Comment: Thank you John. This really helps!